# What am I doing wrong? I keep getting NaN? (Heron's formula)

Tags: java, area

Problem:

> Write a program that reads the lengths of the sides of a triangle from the user. Compare the area of the triangle using Heron's formula, in which s represents half of the perimeter of the triangle and a,b, and c represent the lengths of the three sides.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class AreaOfTriangle
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        final double NUM_ONE = 0.5;
        int a, b, c;
        double s, area;

        System.out.print("Enter side a: ");
        a = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter side b: ");
        b = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter side c: ");
        c = scan.nextInt();

        s = NUM_ONE * (a + b + c);

        area = Math.sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c));

        System.out.println("\nThe area of the triangle = " + area);
    }
}
```

Comment: where do you get it?

Comment: you need to check, if the user gives real triangle sides. For example could the user give you 1 ; 2 and 10, but no one could construct from this a real triangle. This are the cases, when the value in the sqrt() gives you nan. I have the same task now, and two options: check for "real triangles" (sum of each two sides > third side), or to say the user "You need to give in real triangles, darling!"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formula is correct, but `s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c)` could end up being very slightly negative depending on the inputs (due to floating point imprecision). You should test this prior to taking the `sqrt`, and return zero in that instance.

`Math.sqrt` on a negative number will return `NaN`.

Comment: Which can be regarded as a suitable result if the inputs really don't define a triangle.

Comment: So long as the lengths are non-negative, then zero.

Answer (score 3):

Because in some cases with your code you end up with a negative value in your sqrt call:

```
 a = 1;
 b = 2;
 c = 5;

 s = NUM_ONE * (a + b + c);
```

Here s = 4.0 and then your sqrt parameter is 4*3*2*-1 which is negative

Should you use Math.sqrt(Math.abs(...)) instead ?

Comment: Actually I *think* you should return zero rather than `Math.abs`.